# How to follow redirection within the hostname in wget?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, download, wget

I need `wget` to follow redirection when recursive, from e.g. host.com to www.host.com. Normally it doesn't recurse to subdomains and with `-H` key it tries to download the whole Internet. How to make it go just to subdomains of the required site (or at least to www. subdomain)?

Comment: wget follow redirections by default. am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: but it doesn't recurse when redirecting. E.g. if you download www.host.com you get whole site, but if `wget` starts with host.com and it redirects to www.host.com then `wget` downloads only index.html and stops there.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
-D "foo.com,b.foo.com" -H
```

Comment: It's very strict, e.g. for hundred sites I need to launch wget hundred times instead of just launching it ones and going through the list `-i` otherwise it works.